# Getting text to display under an image in a navigation

Tags: css, formatting, styling

I want my navigation to look like this:

```
<icon>       <icon>       <icon>
Title     Longer Title    Title
```

Ideally, I want my code to look like:

```
<li>
    <img src="images/icon.png" />
    <a class="link_title">Title 1</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="images/icon.png"/>
    <a class="link_title">Title 2</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="images/icon.png"/>
    <a class="link_title">Title 3</a>
</li>
```

I already have it horizontal, but not sure how to get the link to appear right under the icon, without using a table, which I don't want to do. (Let me know if I must, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
li { text-align:center; }
li a.link_title { display:block; }
```

Also, you're closing your `<a>` tags with a `</span>`. This needs to be corrected:

```
<a class="link_title">Some Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
li {
float:left;
text-align:center;
}

li a {
display:block;  
}

li img {
margin:0 auto;  
}
```